# How to make Arrays of my JButton/ActionListeners

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm doing a project for school and we need to create a program with many `JButtons`, `ActionListeners`, images, etc. I have created a class with many individual `ActionListeners` and `JButtons`, but how can I change this into an array of buttons rather than creating them all individually?

This is my code...

```
public class Selectie extends JFrame{

    private JButton keeper, verdediger, verdediger1, verdediger2;

    public void initGUI() {
        keeper = new JButton("1. "+""+" Kenneth Vermeer");
        Cursor cur = keeper.getCursor();
        keeper.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        keeper.setBounds(20, 50, 186, 12);
        keeper.setFocusable(false);
        keeper.setBorderPainted(false);
        keeper.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        keeper.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        keeper.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        keeper.setActionCommand(Vermeer);

        verdediger = new JButton("2. "+""+" Gregory van der Wiel");
        Cursor cur1 = verdediger.getCursor();
        verdediger.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger.setBounds(20, 70, 215, 17);
        verdediger.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger.setActionCommand(Gregory);

        verdediger1 = new JButton("3. "+""+" Toby Alderweireld");
        Cursor cur2 = verdediger1.getCursor();
        verdediger1.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger1.setBounds(20, 95, 188, 17);
        verdediger1.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger1.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger1.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger1.setActionCommand(Alderweireld);

        verdediger2 = new JButton("4. "+""+" Jan Vertonghen");
        Cursor cur3 = verdediger2.getCursor();
        verdediger2.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        verdediger2.setBounds(20, 120, 174, 17);
        verdediger2.setFocusable(false);
        verdediger2.setBorderPainted(false);
        verdediger2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        verdediger2.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,17));
        verdediger2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        verdediger2.setActionCommand(Vertonghen);

        SelectieController s1 = new SelectieController(keeper,verdediger,verdediger1,verdediger2);

        keeper.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger1.addActionListener(s1);
        verdediger2.addActionListener(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Retagged to include [tag:homework] and removed irrelevant tags.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without doing all the work, you need to do something like this (you can fill in the blanks - it is your homework after all...)

```
// create the array
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10];

// Repeat for each button...
for (int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
  // create the button
  JButton button = new JButton("label");

  // set the button properties...
  button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
  button.setBounds(20, 95, 188, 17);
  button.setFocusable(false);
  button.setBorderPainted(false);
  button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
  // etc.

  // Assign the listener
  button.addActionListener(s1);

  // Add the button to the array
  buttons[i] = button;
  }
```